# Error with pmatrix inside multline* inside minipage inside tabular

Tags: tables, minipage, multline

The following is a minimal example of code that gives me an `Argument of \multline* has an extra }` error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{c}
  \begin{minipage}{200pt} 
   \begin{multline*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
     a 
     &  
    \end{pmatrix}
   \end{multline*}
  \end{minipage}
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Removing the `tabular` environment kills the error, removing the ampersand kills the error, and changing the `multline*` environment to `$$` kills the error.  Is this a known limitation of the environments involved?  Something related to having things too deeply nested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear why you'd want that level of nesting (eg a p column is rather more natural than a minipage in a c column) but anyway an extra `{}` gets you back on track:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{c}
  {\begin{minipage}{200pt} 
   \begin{multline*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
     a 
     &  
    \end{pmatrix}
   \end{multline*}
  \end{minipage}}
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replacing the c column + minipage with a p column still gives an error:  "Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \multline*."  The workaround with the braces does work, though.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ChrisGrant yes, it would:-) (but still it seemed worth saying:-) ams could have defined multline so it would nest, just as tabular can nest but probably they just thought  it would never be needed (it would complicate the code somewhat).