# tex4ht compile error using mathml switch using multline with pmatrix and easybmat

Tags: amsmath, tex4ht, multline

It took me a long time to find this and be able to make a MWE. I hope someone has an idea what is causing it and if there is a work around. This problem shows up in this small example, only when I use the mathml switch in tex4ht. Which is really strange. I've had problems before using tex4ht with mathml, but these show up in the HTML file, never in the actual compile stage.

I was trying to use a solution to add dashed lines to a matrix as shown [is it possible to add dashed lines between rows/column of pmatrix from amsmath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163587/is-it-possible-to-add-dashed-lines-between-rows-column-of-pmatrix-from-amsmath)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{easybmat}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\bgroup
\renewenvironment{pmatrix}{\left(\begin{BMAT}(@){c.c}{c.c}}
{\end{BMAT}\right)}
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
\egroup
\end{multline*}    
\end{document}
```

compiles with no problem with pdflatex

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But gives this error with tex4ht

```
htlatex foo.tex "htm,mathml"

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html-mml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht))
(./foo.aux)
l.16 --- TeX4ht warning --- \halign translated into linear text ---
! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.
<to be read again> 
                   &
l.16 \end{multline*}                    
?
```

but using this command, it now compiles fine and the HTML file displays fine with the dashed lines in the matrix.

```
htlatex foo.tex "htm"  %ok
```

If I remove the `multline*` environment, it now works ok in both modes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{easybmat}
\begin{document}    
\[
\bgroup
\renewenvironment{pmatrix}{\left(\begin{BMAT}(@){c.c}{c.c}}
{\end{BMAT}\right)}
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
\egroup
\]    
\end{document}

htlatex foo.tex "htm"   %ok
htlatex foo.tex "htm,mathml"  %ok compile, but wrong HTML display on firefox
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above code was small fragment from large file.
Any idea what is causing this error and is there a workaround it? I'd like to use mathml since I use mathjax for final display (in this small example, I did not show this) and like to keep using mathml. I also need to use `\usepackage{easybmat}`.

One final fact point: If I remove the `easybmat` part, then it works OK again:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\begin{pmatrix}
    A & B\\
    C & D
\end{pmatrix}
\end{multline*}    
\end{document}

htlatex foo.tex "htm,mathml"  %ok
htlatex foo.tex "htm"  %ok
```

But I need to use `easybmat` to add the dashed lines as explained in the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163587/is-it-possible-to-add-dashed-lines-between-rows-column-of-pmatrix-from-amsmath)

So the problem shows up, only when using `easybmat` with `multline`. Fyi, here is a question also on error using multline with pmatrix, not sure if it is related [Error with pmatrix inside multline* inside minipage inside tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152931/error-with-pmatrix-inside-multline-inside-minipage-inside-tabular)

texlive 2013, on linux mint 16

```
tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 kpathsea)
```

Comment: the configuration for easybmat doesn't exist. probably easiest fix would be to provide new environment for matrixes instead of redefining `pmatrix`, in the case of pdf generation, use version with `BMAT`, and for html, use normal pmatrix, you can add lines with `css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution for `easybmat` support, but in your particular case you can simplify your code and use different, supported by `tex4ht`, matrix environment . dashed lines can be added with `css`.

First, simplified document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nasser}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}%
\begin{fourmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{fourmatrix}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

`fourmatrix` environment is used instead of explicit `BMAT`, resp. `pmatrix`. It is defined in `nasser.sty` package:

```
\ProvidesPackage{nasser}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{easybmat}

\newenvironment{fourmatrix}{%
\left(\begin{BMAT}(@){c.c}{c.c}}
{\end{BMAT}\right)}
```

note that there is no need to redefine `pmatrix` environment, you can use `BMAT` directly. Now definition for `tex4ht`, `nasser.4ht`:

```
\renewenvironment{fourmatrix}{\begin{pmatrix}}{\end{pmatrix}}
\ConfigureEnv{fourmatrix}{\HCode{<mrow class="fourmatrix">}}{\HCode{</mrow>}}{}{}

\Css{.fourmatrix mtable{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}}

\Css{.fourmatrix mtd{
    border-right:1px dashed black;
}}

\Css{.fourmatrix mtd:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}}

\Css{.fourmatrix mtr{
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}}

\Css{.fourmatrix mtr:last-child{
    border-bottom:none;
}}
```

`fourmatrix` is redefined to use `pmatrix`, which is supported by `tex4ht` instead of `BMAT`. Additional `<mrow class="fourmatrix">` element is added to support styling with `css`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to put the .sty and .4ht files somewhere special for this to work? I put them in same folder as the .tex file, and pdflatex took them and compiled ok. But when I did `htlatex foo.tex` and looked at the html file generated (no errors btw during compiling), I do not see the dashes in the matrix. I see the matrix only. Screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TweLZ.png) I am using tex4ht 2014. screen shot of the folder ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve7N4.png) screen shot of HTML ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2uunr.png)

Comment: @Nasser you can use these files from same folder as your TeX document, but if you want to use them from several projects in different folders, you should place it to `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/nasser`. see http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/installsty.html

Comment: @Nasser this workaround is for `mathml`, it won't work for picture math

Comment: I see. No problem, thank you anyway. I use picture math now, since there are issues with mathml+mathjax as you know, we talked about that before. But will keep this solution for the day I switch back to mathml.